# Rails - Form problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

In my app I have 3 models like that:

```
class Person
has_many :groups
has_many :group_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
end

class Group_Membership
 belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'Person'
 belongs_to :group
end

class Group
belongs_to :person
has_many :group_memberships
has_many :members, :class_name => "Person", :through => "group_memberships", :foreign_key => "member_id"
```

What I need is to create a button in the group#show page, that allows the Person to ask for the group_membership. By suggestion from a previous question I made a `def create_membership` on my Group_Membership controller:

```
def create_membership
  @group = Group.find params[:id]
  if @group.group_memberships.create( :member_id => params[:member_id])
     redirect_to @group
  else
     render :action => 'show'
  end
end
```

So I moved on to my form, on the group#show view, and I did as follow:

```
<%= form_for :group_membership, @group_membership, :url => { :action => "create_membership" } do |f| %>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

But everytime I click on the button, it redirects me to the form to create a new Group, not Group_Membership. Any hints?
Thanks in advance.

**########EDIT##########**

Well, I kinda changed my code to something like this:

```
def create
@person = Person.find(current_person)
@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
params[:group_membership] = {:member_id => @person.id, :group_id => @group.id}
@group_membership = Group_Membership.create(params[:group_membership])
if @group_membership.save
redirect_to @person
else
redirect_to @person
end
end
```

And my form is right now like that:

`<% form_for(:group_membership, :url => group_memberships_path(:member_id => current_person, :group_id => @group.id)) do |f| %>
<%= submit_tag "Join!" %>`

Now I'm able to actually create a group_membership model, but both id's are added blank in database column `member_id` and `group_id`.

If I change the line `@group_membership = Group_Membership.create(params[:group_membership])` to `@group_membership = Group.Group_Membership.create(params[:group_membership])`, I'm able to get group id saved. Same goes if I change to `Person.`.

Comment: maybe you should better use HABTM relationship? it will simplify things What fields do you have in Group_Membership model?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have both ids, from member (Person) and Group, and a boolean `status`, that is `false` by default. My idea is to add a model on `group_membership` always a Person want to join a Group. The Group Owner will accept this membership when he/she changes the `status` to true, and will reject it by destroying the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to clean up a bit

```
def create
  @group_membership = Group_Membership.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]), :member => Person.find(current_person))
  if @group_membership.save
    redirect_to @person
  else
    redirect_to @person
  end
end
```

this code should work in rails 3 I'm not sure about earlier versions

Comment: Both Id's still blank on database. Should I change anything on the forms? Thanks again.

Comment: you should check your development.log file you'll see list of params and sql queries there

Comment: it would be great if you add part to the question

Comment: You can do `if @group_member.save!` so it raises an exception if there's a save issue.

Comment: I checked the log and I found something, I'm getting this line during the POST: `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: group, member`. Is this related to the error?

Comment: Found out the answer for this at this link http://justinleitgeb.com/2010/09/rails-3-0-upgrade-watch-out-for-differences-in-mass-assignment-checks-on-has_many-through-associations/

Thanks for the help you provided!

Comment: Well I did as the links says and worked out one time... but suddenly it doesn't work anymore and the logs shows the same error...

Comment: I created a new question since the subject have changed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062971/rails-warning-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes