# Rails - WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Continuing from here: [Rails - Form problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058486/rails-form-problems), everytime I try to create a new `group_membership` I get this: `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: group, member` at my log and the ID's are added blank.

Have been making changes to the `attr_accessible` of my models but so far no solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add `:group` and `:member` to attr_accessible?

Comment: post your model code, and let's see…

Comment: Thank you! Based on an another answer from stack I was adding :group_attributes and :member_attributes. Make it an answer and I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you add `:group` and `:member` to your `attr_accessible` call :)